# Ubuntu XFCE4 Resolution

Tags: 18.04, xfce, display-resolution

I rented a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 with xfce and vnc already installed and trying to set that up to how I want it. The display resolution is stuck at 800x600.  I went into display settings but it won't show any other resolutions. I looked into other settings and found settings editor and changed the display resolution there but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: VPS likely doesn't have graphics drivers available.  What exact settings ahve you tried to get the higher resolution?  Does the VPS have settings to indicate the 'virtual screen resolution'?  Are you VNC'd or RDP'd into the machine? We need a lot more information to try and assist in solving this.  (VPSes typically don't run GUIs either, just an FYI)

Comment: Only settings I messed with are settings/display  and settings/settings editor and I tried to adjust the display there.  I changed the display under settings editor to 1280x720 I closed it out and it did nothing.  I restarted the vps and no change.  Then I sent back into settings editor it reverted back to 800x600.  I am VNC'd into the machine now

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access to vps - then:
`ps aux | grep Vncserver` then 
 `kill -9 pid of Vncserver` 
then
`vncserver -geometry 1920x1080` 
Resolution can be whatever you want. 
Then reconnect to vps using vnc.

Comment: unless they're using the VNC provided by the VPS provider and not direct-VNC connecting to the VPS itself.  That wouldn't work.  (As I said in my comment to OP, we need more info)

Comment: @ThomasWard then why don't just ask vps provider to setup vncserver resolution?